# sync tailwind bet my nextjs projet and my custom react component lib

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

the issue is my tailwind class use in ma lib don't work if the class are not use directly in my project

for example if i use bg-orange-400 in a component Card in my lib

i import my lib in my nextjs project

i create a component and import my Card component from my custom lib

il will render my Card component with bg-orange-400 in classes but not working
but if i use bg-orange-400 directly in my projet it will work and also in my component

-use the same tailwind version

my lib config

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
const colors = require('tailwindcss/colors')
export default {
  jit: true,
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        primary: colors.teal,
    },
  }
  },
  plugins: [],
  corePlugins: {
    preflight: false,
  },
}
```

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './src/pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './src/components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './src/app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundImage: {
        'gradient-radial': 'radial-gradient(var(--tw-gradient-stops))',
        'gradient-conic':
          'conic-gradient(from 180deg at 50% 50%, var(--tw-gradient-stops))',
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tailwind automatically purges any unused classes during build.

This means that `bg-orange-400` will not be included in the stylesheet of your library if not used and hence will not be recognized in your other project.

You can either

- Point tailwind in your project to look in your library's source code and apply the tailwind classes, by adding the path to your library inside `node_modules` to the `content` property of your project's config file

```js
content: [
  './src/pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
  './src/components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
  './src/app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
  './node_modules/<your_lib_path>/**/*.js',
],
```

Tailwind Docs - [Working with Third-Party libraries](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#working-with-third-party-libraries)

- Safelist the classes you want to include in your final stylesheet (keep even if they are not used)

e.g. safelisting the `bg-orange-400` class would look like this

```js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  safelist: [
    'bg-orange-400'
  ]
  // ...
}
```

Tailwind Docs - [Safelisting Classes](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes)